# GBQ SQL: If value X <> 0 in column A, then count distinct in column B

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following table.

```
Sales   Name
10      Bob
12      Bob
0       Jane
20      Jane
0       Jill
```

I want to count the distinct Names but only for rows where Sales is not equal to zero.

**For the above table, I should get the answer 2 (Bob, Jane).**

I think I should be using a Case When statement but not sure how.

```
CASE WHEN Sales <> 0 THEN COUNT DISTINCT Name...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You an use a pretty simple query:

```
select count(distinct name)
from t
where sales <> 0;
```

If you want only the names, you could use `array_agg()` or:

```
select distinct name
from t
where sales <> 0;
```